# I'm trying to use jQuery to see if a div contains some text, and then add a class to that div if it does

Tags: jquery, html

I think I'm on the right track. So what is going on here is i'm checking to see if the li has text that says "Private" if it does then it adds a class .private to the li element, but for some reason it not working i think it has something to do with the if statement.

Any help would be great. ;)

Bascily code is

```
<ul>
<li>private</li>
<li>blah blah blah</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery Code

```
$( "li" ).each(function() {

  if ($( this ).text("private");) {
     $( this ).addClass(".private");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`if ($( this ).text() === "private")`

You also had an extra semi colon in the `if` statement which would cause problems.
Note that I used 3 equal signs. Change to two if you don't want to use type/case matching.

Also you don't need the period when adding a class. Just use this:

`$( this ).addClass("private");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( this ).addClass(".private");
```

Should be

```
$( this ).addClass("private");
```

You do not need the `.` if you are already using the `addClass()` function.

Also, your `if` statement should be:

```
if ($( this ).text() === "private")
```

Your `if` statement `$( this ).text("private");` would normally change the text of the `selector` so it is not a condition.

Change to this:

```
$("li").each(function () {
    if ($( this ).text() === "private") {
        $(this).addClass("private");
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fqxo6sg7/)**

Comment: Lol downvoting is a joke here

Comment: Nope, I downvoted you when you first submitted your answer since all you did was provide code and didn't explain why it would be used.

Comment: Well, if you waited 30 seconds I posted the explanation. Does it satisfy your needs now?

Comment: Adding a simple/un-finished answer just to try and beat other people doesn't make it a good answer regardless of the amount of edits you make to bring it up to par

Comment: Haha is that so? How much reputation you have again? There is a reason why you can undo your downvote but it is okay, I could care less about your down vote.

Comment: I'm not going to rise to your immaturity. Reputation has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Please explain me the reason as to why they have an undo for downvotes? Next time, please don't downvote to make your answer look better.